# dplyr - group_by and count if variable satisfies condition

Tags: r, grouping, dplyr

I've got a problem that seems quite simple conceptually yet I'm having a hard time accomplishing it in R (and examples I've found online are many (using dplyr) yet do not seem to get at what I'm looking for).  Here's an example below:

I've got 3 variables: Response (factor), Type (factor), and Status (factor).  Basically, I'm trying to figure out how many times (frequency) a particular Response appears for each Type if Status equals 1.  Responses will always be between 0-10.  Below is an example dataframe:

```
Response    Type    Status
5   A   0
5   A   1
2   A   0
0   A   0
6   A   1
1   A   1
9   A   0
3   A   1
4   A   1
0   A   1
9   A   0
1   A   0
0   A   1
7   A   0
5   B   1
4   B   1
4   B   1
8   B   0
7   B   1
8   B   0
2   B   0
0   B   1
10  B   0
3   B   0
1   B   0
9   B   0
4   B   1
1   B   1
```

The end-result I'm looking for is something like what is displayed below, where ResponseScale shows the full range of Response options available (0-10), and Count displays the frequency with which a particular Response appear given the ResponseScale.

```
Type    ResponseScale   Count
A   0   2
A   1   1
A   2   0
A   3   1
A   4   1
A   5   1
A   6   1
A   7   0
A   8   0
A   9   0
A   10  0
B   0   1
B   1   1
B   2   0
B   3   0
B   4   3
B   5   1
B   6   0
B   7   1
B   8   0
B   9   0
B   10  0
```

I've tried using group_by in dplyr without much success (I couldn't get the frequency counts to display by Type--output displayed counts overall collapsed across Type).  But more importantly, I'm not sure how to incorporate the Status equals 1 part that I want within a dplyr example.

Any help/pointers would be appreciated--thanks!

Comment: I think you should consider going through a dplyr tutorial. This is roughly your output. `DF %>% group_by(Type, Response) %>% summarise(n = sum(Status))`

Comment: Thanks @Frank!  Yes, what you have works.  I was wondering if I had to sum the Status values or if there was different way to accomplish the same thing without converting Status to int and do the sum.  Thanks again!

Comment: You can `%>% tally(Status)` as the final step, too. There are a few ways to tabulate with dplyr. You could start with the docs at `?tally` to see more.

Comment: I recommend swirl tutorial, it is very good for dplyr

Comment: Thanks @MatiasAndina!  I will also look up swirl!

Comment: But this is a simple base aggregate: `aggregate(.~Type + Response, df[df$Status==1,], length)`